# Send email when a value changes in Google Sheets

Tags: email

I need some assistance in writing a script. I have a Google Sheet [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6AOl.png) with a column that gets updated from form submission results in another sheet. What I need is for a script to send the message in column B to the address in Column A whenever the value in Column C gets updated. I had a script that kind of worked, but it would send to every email address in column A, anytime any value in column c was updated. There will be many rows, each for a different email address in column A and value in column C.

I'm not a professional developer but I have some experience writing scripts.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please show what you tried so far.

Comment: I am using a script that I found from a Google Product Expert.I only changed values in the section marked [START modifiable parameters]. I added an onEdit trigger as well. I am getting a notice that the script successfully runs, but I am not getting the email.

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FtSyOIWjiw6L7SoRkMzj6-IAcCxxGcwZSmTIVd69u6U/edit?usp=sharing)